# wix and heat configure installation folder

Tags: xml, wix, installation, heat

I work with WiX and i would include files and another folder to my installer.

Actually I have this project.wixproj :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="wixfile1.wxs" />
    <Compile Include="wixfile2.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
...
```

And two .wxs files (wixfile1.wxs):

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    ...

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
                <Directory Id="test" Name="test" >
                    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Application test"/>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>


        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
            <Component Id="myimg.png" Guid="7435781f-2bf1-4f1b-8376-754c2d4dac68">
                <File Id="myimg" Source="C:\imglol.png" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>

        </DirectoryRef>


        <Feature Id="myimg" Title="Main image" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="myimg.png" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

And by example the wixfile2.wxs which are generated by heat command line. I would deploy all folder named "API".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>


        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="dirA4F7A43D3DBF467AC127F1422D00240E" Name="API">
                <Component Id="cmpCCEB1A915DCA242C688E53A21CE3C3CD" Guid="{}">
                    <File Id="fil0507E8B9603778F116316274B82F92D9" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Library.Def.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp4D36C9F3F381088827D9A606380954B9" Guid="{}">
                    <File Id="fil1E594FEBC557E93E0B15FC1DC3DE315F" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\APPli.CFG" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpF940CA5BFB57C855744EC0E727B0B13E" Guid="{}">
                    <File Id="fil5488939102DA1D694DFD42512F2BBD77" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\AppControl.cgf" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp8FB86D8D349378672E4CCD03AF81F56D" Guid="{}">
                    <File Id="filBF7F9A64772328CD9FBCB2EABD140A91" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Application.Configuration.xml" />
                </Component> ........ and others folders and file
```

But when i compile my wixproj, it's works but after running the installer just the myimg.png are deployed in the right place but API isn't deployed.

Could i have forgotten few things ?

**Edit1:**
Now with bradfordrg solution i have this error at the wixproject compilation :

> "C:\project.wixproj" (cible par défaut) (1) ->(Link cible)
>   ->C:\wixfile1.wxs(25): error LGHT0094: Unresolved rference to symbol 'Component:MyAPP' in section 'Product:*'. [C:\project.wixproj]

Into wixfile2 i have :

```
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="APP">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpFE6698874FDA6C78569E0859730A1EEA" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpB50D6DA51C4E18ACC1DA69264417232D" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp1D36D13E7527C1AA7991A8BA6BD00215" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpA22778B0611224EC3606522B68E34E2D" />
....
```

and wixfile1.wxs i have :

```
<Feature Id="myimg" Title="Main image" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="myimg.png" />
    <ComponentRef Id="APP" />
        </Feature>
```

It's good no ?

Comment: Where you want to deploy the API? TARGETDIR is defaulted to root drive.  So Add some other directory under SourceDir in Wix file1 for API and refer that Directory ID in WIX file2. It will work.

Comment: in the same directory that myimg.png /Myapplication/myimg.png and /My application/API/...

Comment: In that case you have to add "APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" in DirectoryRef  wix file 2.

Comment: it doesn't work, i always have just myimg.png but no /API/ folder into /My application/

Comment: At the end of my wixfile2, how specifed the install directory like <feature> block into the wixfile1 ?

Comment: You could add ComponentGroupRef of WIX file 2 to wix file 1 feature. It will link all components from WIX file 2.

Comment: Can you illustrate that, i don't understand how i could add ComponentGroupRef between my two wixfile.

Comment: Second WIX file you will have one componentgroup id. Put that id in first wix file.
<Feature Id="myimg" Title="Main image" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="myimg.png" />
            <componentgroupref ID="" />
 </Feature>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like the **heat.exe** generated components are not being referenced by any `<Feature...>` element.

When you run heat.exe to generate `wixfile2.wxs`, use the `-cg MyAPI` option to generate a `<ComponentGroup...>` element in the file.  This should add this type of content to `wixfile2.wxs`:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyAPP">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpCCEB1A915DCA242C688E53A21CE3C3CD" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp4D36C9F3F381088827D9A606380954B9" />
        ...
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Then reference the new component group in the feature declared in `wixfile1.wxs`:

```
<Feature Id="myimg" Title="Main image" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="myimg.png" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyAPP" />
</Feature>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try it. Now I understand better what vinoth meant.

Comment: I tried it, but i have an error with the build, look my post edit.

Comment: Do you have a typo?  The ComponentRef/@Id should match the argument to the `-cg` command.  For example if you have `-cg MyAPI`, the corresponding reference should be `<ComponentRef Id="MyAPI" />`.

Comment: No my command contain '-cg APP' and My ComponentRef Id="APP", i don't undestand why it doesn't works

Comment: It turns out I had a typo in my answer.  Within your `<Feature..>` element, you need to add a `<ComponentGroupRef...>` element to reference the heat generated component group.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oh no problem :)  thank you but just question : now the build indicate that system don't find the file SourceDir\(subfolderorFileofAPPfolder). But into my heat command i specified path dir "C:\APP". I don't understand why heat remplace in the path wixfile2 by "SourceDir\"